# Convert decimal to date in order to use DATENAME function

Tags: sql, sql-server

Working with an ERP database (SQL Server) that stores dates as decimal columns in `YYYYMMDD` format - e.g. `20160801`. I need to convert these values into dates so that I can use the `DATENAME` function to identify the day of the week corresponding to each date.

Or, if there is another way to derive the day of the week, I am all ears. The rest of the query is simple ... I just need to return an Order Number, the Order Date (the column stored as a decimal), and the day of the week corresponding to the Order Date.

**EDIT (taken from a comment)**

I am still missing something as I'm getting a could not be bound error:

```
Select CAST(OEORDD.EXPDATE AS VARCHAR(8)) 
DECLARE @dec DECIMAL(10,0)=20160801; 
SELECT CAST(CAST(@dec AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) , sum(OEORDD.EXTWEIGHT) as ExtWeight 
FROM OEORDD 
GROUP BY EXPDATE
```

Comment: `convert(date, convert(varchar(8), decimal_date))`. You also can consider creating a computed column for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the "unserparated" datetime format, which is casteable natively. For this you'd need an 8-letter-string with *yyyymmdd*.

So first convert your decimal number to a string:

```
CAST(YourDecimalValue AS VARCHAR(8))
```

Then cast this to a date:

```
DECLARE @dec DECIMAL(10,0)=20160801;
SELECT CAST(CAST(@dec AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)
```

**UPDATE (concerning your comment)**

Might be you need something like this:

```
SELECT  CAST(CAST(OEORDD.EXPDATE AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE) AS YourConvertedDate
       ,SUM(OEORDD.EXTWEIGHT) AS ExtWeight 
FROM OEORDD 
GROUP BY CAST(CAST(OEORDD.EXPDATE AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help; I am still missing something as I'm getting a could not be bound error: Select 

CAST(OEORDD.EXPDATE AS VARCHAR(8))

DECLARE @dec DECIMAL(10,0)=20160801;
SELECT CAST(CAST(@dec AS VARCHAR(8)) AS DATE)

 , sum(OEORDD.EXTWEIGHT) as ExtWeight


FROM OEORDD
GROUP BY EXPDATE

Comment: @DavidGelula, please use the edit option of your question to add your current query (reduced to the necessary). I cannot help you without any knowledge of your code...

Comment: @DavidGelula, Ah, I see your code now in the comment... You should use only the parts you need. My code with the variable `@dec` is just an example... You need **the last line only** and replace the `@dec` with your actual column or variable...

Answer (score 2):

You can use it for Text or Number of a week day:

```
DECLARE @d DECIMAL = 20160801;
SELECT DATENAME(dw,CAST(CAST(@d as VARCHAR(8)) as DATE)),
    DATENAME(d,CAST(CAST(@d as VARCHAR(8)) as DATE)),
    @d;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @decimal DECIMAL(10,0)=20160801;
SELECT DATENAME(dw,CAST(convert(VARCHAR(8),@decimal) AS DATE))
```